# How to set shipping method to shipping class in woo commerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, usps

How to set shipping method to shipping class. like an example

Flate rate shipping class - Flate rate method
Usps Shipping class - Usps Method

Or

How can we by hook also?

Comment: which plugin you are using?

Comment: Woocommerce and woocommerce usps plugin

Comment: check this article https://www.xadapter.com/hide-shipping-methods-shipping-classes-exist-not-exist-cart/

Answer (score 0):

Use `woocommerce_package_rates` hook.This will do the trick
 add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'manage_method_basedon_shipping_class', 10, 2);

```
function manage_method_basedon_shipping_class($methods, $package)
{
    // $package have cart  items, so loop through that and get your shipping classes available in the cart. like $item->get_shipping_class().

// So you have all the classes now. Now based on this unset shipping methods from $method function. $method have all available shipping methods 

// now return $methods;

}
```

I have written logic in the above code, not with actual shipping IDs. This is pretty easy. You can manage it.